# How is this property called scope being injected onto this attribute in doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

In doorkeeper, I see the [following code](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/rails/routes.rb#L27):

```
def generate_routes!(options)
        @mapping = Mapper.new.map(&@block)
        routes.scope options[:scope] || 'oauth', as: 'oauth' do
          map_route(:authorizations, :authorization_routes)
          map_route(:tokens, :token_routes)
          map_route(:tokens, :revoke_routes)
          map_route(:applications, :application_routes)
          map_route(:authorized_applications, :authorized_applications_routes)
          map_route(:token_info, :token_info_routes)
        end
      end
```

Where is the "scope" property on "routes.scope" coming from?  Is it somehow being injected via ActionDispatch?

Comment: Line: 18 `attr_accessor :routes`

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/c13ab298489945964db4f45ab3c37885223d28b8/spec/dummy/config/routes.rb#L3, there you can find many examples.

Comment: @7urkm3n, I see where "routes" is coming from as an attr_accessor but not where scope is coming from...how is scope a property on routes?

Comment: @fanta that code you pointed to is passing a "scope" option, how is it attaching itself as a property / method on the "routes" object?